# Hybrid Crypto implementation over network socket between Java and C++

Tags: java, c++, sockets, encryption, hybrid

I am attempting a hybrid-cryptography implementation between 2 applications, one Java and the other C++. Rather than relying on key storage in a file, Im trying to send the keys as a byte array over the socket and have the receiving application recreate the key from the byte array. Along the lines of

1. Java: Generate public/private key pair (RSA)
2. Java: Transmit public key to C++ application
3. C++: Receive public key and recreate
4. C++: Generate session key (symmetric, AES) and encrypt with received public key
5. C++: Transmit encrypted session key
6. Java: Receive session key and decrypt with private key of the RSA key pair

At this point the 2 applications would have the symmetrical key and proceed to exchange traffic using it for encryption and decryption. My problem is at step 3. On receiving the public key as a byte array, I cannot successfully recreate it.

Java

```
GenerateSymmetricKey genSymKey;
private static PrivateKey privateKey;
private static PublicKey publicKey;

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
    // Generate public/private key pair
    GenerateKeys sk = new GenerateKeys(1024);
    sk.createKeys();
    privateKey = sk.getPrivateKey();
    publicKey = sk.getPublicKey();

    String server = "localhost";
    int port = 8083;

    try {

        // Establish socket connection
        InetAddress serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(server);
        Socket serverConnection = new Socket(serverAddress, port);

        // Setup output streams
        OutputStream os = serverConnection.getOutputStream();

        os.write(publicKey.getEncoded());
        os.flush();
```

C++

```
if ( m_socket->bytesAvailable() > 8)
{
    int len =  m_socket->bytesAvailable();
    QByteArray encryptArray = m_socket->readAll();
    encryptArray.resize(len);

    QByteArray clientPublic = encryptArray.toBase64();
    clientPublic.prepend("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n");
    clientPublic.append("\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n");

    QSslCertificate clientCert(clientPublic);
    QSslKey sslKey(clientPublic, QSsl::Rsa, QSsl::Pem, QSsl::PublicKey, "testtest");

    qDebug() << "Client sslKey: " << sslKey.isNull();
```

The sslkey is always null. I am using Crypto++ on the C++ side. Can this be done? Examples I have seen save the keys to file rather than transmit them over the network.

Comment: The problem with this algorithm is that the Java application cannot be sure that it is talking to the correct machine.  If the message in step 2 is intercepted, then the connection can be hijacked without the Java application being able to detect it.

Comment: It doesn't look like crypto++, it looks like Qt. And a public key is not a certificate. And finally, it looks like your trying to do ssl manually.

Comment: This system isn't actually secure.  In my opinion, you are wasting your time and should just use TLS.

Comment: Thanks or the responses. I have read elsewhere that implementing your own was not recommended but I had always assumed that meant implementing your own libraries. Making use of the existing libraries in Java and Crypto++ to then implement your own scheme I thought would be possible. What is the intended purpose of them if this is not a recommended practice?